# Can not locate config makefile for product "cm_oneplus2"

Tags: android, linux, git, makefile

I've been trying to build AOSP ROM for OnePlus Two.

1. I've made a `working-dir` folder in my `ubuntu's home`. Installed all required tools and scripts like, java, python, make, git and some lib files.
2. I've downloaded compressed sources(No `.repo` folder included), so I've only `aosp5.1.0` folder with me. I've downloaded them form here. ([Heavily Compressed Android Sources](https://forum.xda-developers.com/android/software/sources-android-sources-highly-t3231109)). Extracted them to `working-dir` using terminal.
3. I've cloned `device tree` from this repository

https://github.com/krishna422/android_device_oneplus_oneplus2 into working-dir/device/oneplus/oneplus2

5. I've cloned `kernel source` from this repository

https://github.com/krishna422/android_kernel_oneplus_msm8994 into working-dir/kernel/oneplus/oneplus2

6. I've cloned `vendor tree` from this repository

https://github.com/krishna422/proprietary_vendor_oneplus into working-dir/vendor/oneplus/oneplus2

So the files in `working-dir` are,

> aosp5.1.0, device, kernel, vendor

files in `aosp5.1.0` are

[Files in aosp5.1.0 Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2a8x.jpg)

I've copied

> working-dir/device/oneplus/ folder into aosp5.1.0/device

then, I opened cmd, navigated to `aosp5.1.0` folder typed `source build/envsetup.sh`

I got

```
krishna@krishna:~/working-dir/aosp5.1.0$ source build/envsetup.sh

including device/generic/mini-emulator-armv7-a-neon/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-arm64/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-x86_64/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-x86/vendorsetup.sh
including device/generic/mini-emulator-mips/vendorsetup.sh
including evice/oneplus/android_device_oneplus_oneplus2/vendorsetup.sh
including sdk/bash_completion/adb.bash
```

then I typed `lunch` I got,

```
krishna@krishna:~/working-dir/aosp5.1.0$ lunch
You're building on Linux

Lunch menu... pick a combo:
     1. aosp_arm-eng
     2. aosp_arm64-eng
     3. aosp_mips-eng
     4. aosp_mips64-eng
     5. aosp_x86-eng
     6. aosp_x86_64-eng
     7. m_e_arm-userdebug
     8. mini_emulator_arm64-userdebug
     9. mini_emulator_x86_64-userdebug
     10. mini_emulator_x86-userdebug
     11. mini_emulator_mips-userdebug
     12. cm_oneplus2-user
     13. cm_oneplus2-userdebug
     14. cm_oneplus2-eng

Which would you like?
```

when I selected `12,13,14`, I get the following error, others are working well.

```
build/core/product_config.mk:222: *** Can not locate config makefile for product "cm_oneplus2".  Stop.

** Don't have a product spec for: 'cm_oneplus2'
** Do you have the right repo manifest?

krishna@krishna:~/working-dir/aosp5.1.0$
```

Please help

Comment: Did you get it building?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to have a file called `AndroidProducts.mk` in your device tree. Put something like the following in it.

```
PRODUCT_MAKEFILES := \
    $(LOCAL_DIR)/oneplus2.mk
```

It should match what you have in the `vendorsetup.sh` and the `oneplus2.mk` should exist.

See the example in the LineageOS repo

https://github.com/LineageOS/android_device_oneplus_oneplus2

Comment: where exactly in the folder hierarchy should this `AndroidProducts.mk` file must be?

Comment: In the root of your device tree. See the link to the LineageOS repo

Comment: @opticyclic There is no AndroidProducts.mk. "LineageOS repo" means some hundreds of git repositories, on which one do you think? In the whole checkout-ed tree (with the tool "repo"), there are about 30 AndroidProducts.mk files.

Comment: If you just click the link it will take you to the oneplus2 device tree directly where you can see the AndroidProducts.mk file.